# 403 error with codeignitor

Tags: codeigniter

When I type in the standard web address for my site, I get a 403 error.  However, when I type in a more exact address, say pointing to an index.php file, everything shows up fine.

I'm using Anodyne Productions' Nova (SMS 3) which uses codeignitor.  All accompanying software (PHP/MySQL) is compatible.

I'm not a very technical person, so I'm hoping that this is an easy fix.

Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the tip.  I ultimately dealt with the issue by setting up a redirect in CPanel.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter uses the [Front-Conroller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) pattern, which means all requests are marshalled through a single controller, in this case index.php

If you don't want that to show up in the URL, you need to setup up rewrites on your server.

The [CodeIgniter Wiki](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/) has a pretty comprehensive explanation.

Answer (score 0):

By using  `mod_rewrite`, the "redirection" is done automatically and removes the index.php from the url, it's easier than handling everything manually through the cPanel really.

I'm running a CodeIgniter website myself on my server and it's working perfectly, [read this](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)